# emacs deamon how to keep mode-line-frame-identification at 1

Tags: menu-bar

Each time when I open a new file using `emacsclient -t -q file.txt`, `mode-line-frame-identification` number keep increases. What is the reason for it, and can I reaccess to previously numbered frames?

```
-UU-:---F1
-UU-:---F2
-UU-:---F3
...
-UU-:---F50
```

Is it possible to keep it at `1`, or when `emacsclient` starts connect to `F1` instead of incrementing its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you connect to emacs with `emacsclient -t`, it creates a new frame, hence the number keeps increasing. Those frames are destroyed when you disconnect with <kbd>C-x #</kbd>, so there's no way to get back to them.

If you want to change what's displayed in the mode-line, you can change `mode-line-format` to remove or replace `mode-line-frame-identification`.